# Which is better in the Rossolimo Sicilian, 3... e6 or 3... g6?

Tags: opening, analysis, learning, sicilian-defense

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "5"]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5
```

In this opening is it better to do e6 to activate the dark square bishop which will protect c5 pawn. If the opponent plays Bxc6, it will have a double pawn in the c file but the dark squared bishop might help the pawn on c5 or g6 because I think the Bishop will be much better on the long diagonal. Also keeping open the option to recapture on c6 with the d-pawn to open the Queen and light squared Bishop. Also not worried about them doubling the pawns because of the Bishop pair to compensate.

I gave my explanation for both moves but which move do you think is Better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's really a matter of taste and style. One option may suit more your style than the other. But if you believe in a "[moneyball approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moneyball)", 3...e6 appears to be the "best" move for black based on a search on the [365chess.com](https://www.365chess.com/opening.php?m=6&n=327&ms=e4.c5.Nf3.Nc6.Bb5&ns=3.3.4.37.327) website. [image] 
Regarding the number of games, I guess that the difference in black's winning chances (30.2% for 3...e6) versus (26% for 3...g6) should be statistically significant.

When you control for the level of players by focusing on the Master Database, the statistics also appear to favor 3...e6 over 3...g6.
[image]